# cron jobs set for different times, but execute at the same time.

Tags: cron

I have a file which I loaded into crontab with the following jobs:

```
# script1 executes at 12:30 daily
# script2 executes at 12:35 daily

30 12 * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O temp.txt http://<host-url>/cronjob/script1.php 

35 12 * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O temp.txt http://<host-url>/cronjob/script2.php
```

I followed the rules as per this site:

[How to Set-up a Cron Job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)

I initially had an issue with having both jobs display in the crontab list. I resolved that issue by having all jobs set up on one line as detailed in the section of:

Dealing with Error Messages from Crontab

Once I had both jobs listed correctly, I tested to verify that they executed correctly. At 12:31 I noted that both scripts executed.

Why did this occur? How can I schedule it so that script2 executes at it's own scheduled time?

I realize this is not such a huge issue but I am curious to know.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: It is weird... You can create a wrapper that checks the data. In case it is 12.30, exit; in case it is 12.35, proceed.

Comment: @fedorqui Sorry I don't follow, for this is my first time trying to set up multiple cron jobs. Could you provide a link or an example?

Comment: Mmmm for debugging what I would suggest is to have a script doing the call to `wget`, instead of doing the `wget` directly from crontab. But this can come later. Now let's focus on why it is not working. What do you get if you do `crontab -l`?

Comment: I get a listing of the jobs as displayed `# runs daily at 2:00 am and 2:35 am`
`30 12 * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O temp.txt http://<host-url>/cronjob/script1.php 35 12 * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O temp.txt http://<host-url>/cronjob/script2.php`

Comment: It is very weird and cannot think about any logical reason for this to happen. Voting to move to [su], as over there they can probably offer a better help than here ([so] programming specific).

Comment: Thank you. I will inquire there. See if I never tested for this scenario I would of never noticed this and would of been happy to report that it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened the cron job to be edited using:

```
crontab -e
```

And made edits using **Nano**.

I added a new line character between jobs and this fixed the problem.

So the file initially created was done on a Windows machine which was FTP to the server. I checked out the file and it was created in Notepad++ without an extension, also tried with an extension of .TXT. The **EOL** character was set to **UNIX**.

No matter the scenario, when loading the file, both jobs executed on the first scheduled time. After I modified cron jobs using the edit above. The cron jobs executed at the scheduled time (aka 5 minutes apart).